# GWT HTML5 offline web-application dynamic manifest

Tags: html, gwt, offline-caching, offline-mode

I have recently converted one GWT web application to be capable to work in HTML5 offline mode. So far seems to work fine but I'm wondering if it's a good idea to serve different `cache.manifest` versions for different browsers?

As we know, GWT will need only one permutation for one target browser (in case of one language, let's make it simple). And it's obvious that we would need to download just one `XXXXXX.cach.html` for one target browser.

I see it's possible as on the serverside I could check `User-Agent` HTTP header and return contents of the appropriate version of my cache.manifest, accordingly setting all headers in order not to break offline status checking behavior. The rest of resources would be served with no custom filtering.

Is this a good idea to optimize it this way? Is there anything I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident, I came across the following project: [Mobile GWT](https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/). Quick documentation ([HTML5 Manifest](https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/HTML5Manifest)) and code ([HTML5ManifestServletBase](https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mgwt/linker/server/Html5ManifestServletBase.java)) review reveals that manifest is prepared considering each client, so that only required resources are sent over the network. Pity,- I was just about to make my own open source solution...